# Can I make a shortcut that leads to a location within a root folder (so to speak), regardless of where that folder is located?

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts, links

I have a clip related to stuff that's in folders "a" and "b", which are subdirectories of a common parent folder, which I’ll refer to as "root". 
The clip is placed in folder "b". I want to create a shortcut that lets me access the clip from inside "a", REGARDLESS of what the location of "root" is (e.g., c:\whatever\gnash\root OR f:\ding\root). Is that possible?
Using Windows 7.

Comment: Have you played around with [MKLink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) yet by chance?

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with symbolic links, which are different from shortcuts. Suppose we have your two folders `a` and `b`, with `mydoc.txt` inside `b`. To create a symbolic link to that file that resides in `a`, open an administrative command prompt in `a`, and use this command:

```
mklink thedoc.txt ..\b\mydoc.txt
```

You can use any name for the symbolic link (the first parameter). Close the command prompt when you're finished. The symbolic link retains the relative path, rather than resolving it to an absolute path. Therefore, you can move the entire `root` structure wherever you want and the symbolic link will still work.

Caution: Explorer sometimes gets stuck when copying symbolic links, especially across volumes. If you need to move the `root` structure, you might want to use this command:

```
robocopy C:\source\root E:\dest\root /e /move /sl
```

---

The symlink strategy has other downfalls too, particularly that it works only on NTFS. You might be able to simply create a normal shortcut and rely on Windows's [link tracking features](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.10.windowsconfidential.aspx). In many cases, Windows can find the target even if it doesn't exist at its last known full path.

Comment: It took a bit more research on symlinks on my part to make it work, but I did it, thank you very much! 
Regarding your edit: how well do symlinks work when I try to copy them on DVDs or Clouds, for instance?

Comment: Unfortunately, symbolic links are an NTFS feature, so they will probably not work on DVDs or in web uploads. In particular, zipping a symlink will actually include the file that it points to, rather than the symlink itself. If that's a deal-breaker, you might have some success with traditional shortcuts - Windows has some fancy behavior to find the target if it moves and automatically fix the shortcut.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a deal breaker. I've noticed the Windows shortcut behavior and it perplexed me, I was like "How does this shortcut still work? I've moved the folders!". But now that I know it's an actual feature, I'll check it out and see if I can make it do what I want it to do. Thank you again for the help!